# Creating "static" taxonomies to choose from, inside custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, menus, taxonomy, customization

Alright, so i have a custom post type called Blurbs (translated, sort of). I want to add a static set of categories for the posts within Blurbs (i don't want the user to be able to create custom categories). I want two different types of categories; links and page-excerpts. I did some reading and came to the conclusion that taxonomies is the way to go for adding these "categories" to the post type.

I got as far as creating the taxonomy, but i don't want it visible in the menu. I just want the "category"-box on the edit/publish screen, with the two static items.

This is what i have so far:

```php
$labels = array(
    'name' => 'Categories',
    'singular_name' => 'Category',
    'search_items' => 'Search categories',
    'all_items' => 'All categories',
    'edit_item' => 'Change category',
    'update_item' => 'Update category',
    'add_new_item' => 'Create new category',
    'new_item_name' => 'New category name'
);

register_taxonomy('categories', array('blurb'), array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
));
```

By setting the `show_ui` to `false`, it disappears from both places (menu and links-box).

So, the two questions i need help with is:

1. How do i remove it from the menu?
2. How do i give it "static" options (aka categories) to choose from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make it `show_ui => false`

   Then to show it on the post edit screen add the box manually

   ```
   add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_boxes_function');

   function meta_boxes_function() {
        add_meta_box('categoriesdiv', 'categories', 'post_categories_meta_box', 'blurb', 'side', null, array('taxonomy' => 'categories'));
   }
   ```
2. use this code for every static term

   ```
   if(!term_exists('term1', 'categories'))
       wp_insert_term('term1', 'categories');
   ```

Comment: Isn't it smarter to keep show_ui=true and just disable the menu option by setting show_in_nav_menus to false? Also, about the wp_insert_term(), where do i place that code? Do i need to run it on every load (if so, should i place it in functions.php?) or just once to add the "category" to the db? And after adding the categories, how do i disable the option for users to add new categotries? - EDIT: Just saw Macgyver's update, show_in_nav_menus won't work, i'll go with your solution on that one.

Comment: `'show_ui' => false` would be enough to not show it to the user even if they type the url directly in the address bar, hiding from menu won't protect against this. The code basically checks if the term exists & insert it if not. You may run it once or as many times as you want, but if you can just remove the code once the term is added to the DB( for better performance)

Comment: Seems good then! I can't test it right now but i'll test it as soon as again, which will be tomorrow. I'll post back to let you know how/if it worked. Thanks bud!

Comment: The box still has the "Create new category" link below the box, is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: Yes, just search wp directory for the function `post_categories_meta_box`. Copy the function to theme's functions.php, rename the function, modify the html to remove that link. Then in the above code, replace the function name to your new function name

Comment: Alright then, i'll see what i can do! Another unrelated question, do you know how to get all posts from a custom post type in a special category? For example, i want all the posts from the "blurf" custom post type in the category "links".

Comment: `get_posts(array('post_type'=>'blurf','category'=>'links'));` Check this codex page for a full reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: blurb*, my bad. It's not working, could it be because "links" is not an actual category, it's a taxonomy item in a taxonomy called "categories"..?

Comment: if it's taxonomy, change 'category' to '{$taxonomy_name}', here 'categories'

Comment: Yup, already tried that. Take a look at my code: http://pastebin.com/p2uV9vpt see anything wrong?

Comment: You're using term name, right? You have to use the slug. Check these 2 examples http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: I figured that would be the case, but how do i get the slug? Just so we're on the same page, this is how it looks like: http://i.imgur.com/cQK9c.png I need to get the slug for the "Länk-puffar" (aka links) taxonomy.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4M9kdxdF Another way is that you can customize the slug with 3rd parameter of `wp_insert term`. You'll find all the details in the respective codex

Comment: Success! Although it probably is much smarter to fetch by the slug, i really don't give a crap anymore! Thanks a bunch for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

There's a much simplier (and more secure way*) way than hiding the user interface (`show_ui=false`) and adding a custom metabox to only display terms: removing the user's ability to manage terms.

If you remove the capability of the user to manage terms not only do you have a secure solution, but user interface takes care of itself. As part of the `register_taxonomy()` you can specify the capabilities the user must have to manage/edit/delete and assign terms.

```
 register_taxonomy( 
    'categories',
    array( 'blurb' ),
    array( 
      ...
      'show_ui' => true,
      'capabilities' => array(
        'manage_terms' => 'a_capability_the_user_doesnt_have',
        'edit_terms'   => 'a_capability_the_user_doesnt_have',
        'delete_terms' => 'a_capability_the_user_doesnt_have',
        'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
      ),
      ...
    )
 )
```

For the first three you'll want to set the capability to something the user doesn't have. In fact, leaving it as above will probably do. If **you** still want to manage/edit/delete terms you can always use a capability that you have but your client does (can they `manage_options`, for instance?). That will allow you to create and maintain the 'static' list. Or you can simply do that before you make the above changes.

Lastly you'll want to give a capability to `assign_terms` the user *does* have. By default, it is `edit_posts`, so you're probably ok to leave it at that. However you may want to create a new capability `edit_blurb`, so that you can allow your user to edit blurbs, but not posts.

WordPress, then handles the rest. As the user cannot manage/edit/delete terms, the admin menu is gone. Furthermore the metabox on the edit blurb page displays only existing terms, and the user cannot add/remove or edit any.

---

*Remember that hiding UI doesn't remove the user's *ability*  to edit, and delete terms, it just hides it.

Answer (score 0):

You should first use the menu to get to the taxonomy management page to add the static values you want to add, then remove it from public consumption.

From:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Use the show_in_nav_menus variable in your taxonomy arguments, i.e.:

```
register_taxonomy('categories', array('blurb'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
      ));
```

Comment: Looks good! That solves one of my problems, my second problem is creating "static" categories, and disabling the option to create new ones.

Comment: this won't work. `show_in_nav_menus` handles if they are available for adding in the navigation menus, not the wordpress admin menu

Comment: Ah crap, hopefully Mdiruls answer works better!

Answer (score 0):

This code runs "wp_insert_term" only when needed (only when querying for all terms) for better performances

```
register_taxonomy(
  'categories',
  null,
  array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => array(
      'name' => 'Categories'
    ),
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'categories'),
  )
);

function create_default_taxonomies_values ($terms, $taxonomies, $args) {
  if ($args['get'] != 'all') return $terms;
  if (empty($taxonomies[0]) || $taxonomies[0] != 'categories') return $terms;

  // default values here:
  $default_values = array('Value 1', 'Value 2');

  foreach ($default_values as $value) {
    if (!term_exists($value, 'categories')) {
      wp_insert_term($value, 'categories');
      return get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    }
  }

  return $terms;
}
add_filter('get_terms', 'create_default_taxonomies_values', 10, 3);
```

Comment: This would ensure that the default values always existed, but it wouldn't stop a user editing them or creating new ones (which I believe is what qwerty was after). If you could prevent a user from editing/adding/removing terms, you could create the default terms manually and leave it at that - that would save having to check the term exists on every page load.