# How to prevent multiple custom terms from being created

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have 2 functions that I'm using to prevent users from creating any further terms within a specific custom taxonomy (teacher-avail).

How would I edit both/either functions to have an array of taxonomies?

1st function

```
add_action('create_term','undo_create_term',10, 3);

function undo_create_term ($term_id, $tt_id, $taxonomy) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )  {
        if($taxonomy == 'teacher-avail') {
        wp_delete_term($term_id,$taxonomy);
        }
    }
}
```

2nd function

```
function disallow_insert_term($term, $taxonomy) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( $taxonomy === 'teacher-avail' && in_array('teacher', $user->roles) ) {
        return new WP_Error(
            'disallow_insert_term', 
            __('Your role does not have permission to add terms to this taxonomy')
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_insert_term', 'disallow_insert_term', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Why don't you just set proper term creating capabilities when you _register_ the taxonomy?

Comment: Users are using a front end form to create a post and for some strange reason it is generating a nameless term in certain custom taxonomies. How would I set a term creating capability when I register a taxonomy?

Comment: It seems [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/creating-static-taxonomies-to-choose-from-inside-custom-post-type#) answers the question as per what tosco indicated.
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/creating-static-taxonomies-to-choose-from-inside-custom-post-type#